# Run function in href flask

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, href

I have my website with thwo hrefs and under this hrefs i have my flask function download_file(). It's working but now I add on my function in flask a parameter. So now I want to run something like that download_file(1) when someone clicked on first href and download_file(2) when someone clicked on href2

```
<h2>Download a file </h2>

<p>

<a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}">Download1</a>

<a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}">Download2</a>

</p>
```

```
############ FLASK CODE

from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def download():
    return render_template('indexdownload.html')


@app.route('/download')
def download_file(number):
    p = "test"
    if number == 1:
        p = "1.txt"
    elif number == 2:
        p = "2.txt"

    return send_file(p, as_attachment=True)


app.run()
```

I try different ways but I always get some syntax errors because I don't know hot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

An anchor with an href attribute sends a GET request.
There are several alternative ways to send data within a GET request.

###### Variable Rule

One way to pass data within a URL is to use [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules). The values are embedded within the path, extracted server-side, and passed to the endpoint as arguments.

```
@app.route('/download/<int:num>')
def download(num):
    # ...
```

###### URL Parameter

An alternative is to pass it as a URL parameter. In this case, the data must be requested within the endpoint and are not necessarily available.
The respective parameter is queried using the name of the object [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args). It is possible to define a default value and optionally to automatically convert the value by specifying a type.

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    num = request.args.get('num', 0, type=int)
    # ...
```

In both cases you can pass the value to the jinja2 statement `url_for` to form the url.

`url_for('download', num=1)`

Based on the code within the request and the intended use, I would suggest the first variant. So you are assuming that a value is specified. You can put your filename together and deliver the file.
Incidentally, you can also pass an entire file name within the URL.

```
@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    # ...
```

```
<a href="{{ url_for('download', filename='1.txt') }}">Download</a>
```